# mac os x 10.6.8 cannot use any command -Example: -bash: ls: command not found

Tags: macos, html-lists, prompt

I cannot use even ls command.

Before this happen I created a .profile file and 
save this line

export PATH:....

I believe I gave wrong path.
Is there a way to find .profile file.

Thanks

Comment: `/bin/ls`. for truly hosed systems, `echo *` can be an emergency backup.

Comment: I cannot even use cd command only echo * works. echo * gives me bunch of file names

Comment: `cd` is a shell built-in command. if you've got a shell prompt, it's pretty much impossible for cd to NOT work, unless you're trying to cd to a directory which doesn't exist.

Comment: I gave pwd then This is what I got: /Users/tom  Then I tried ls I got -bash: ls: command not found

Comment: yes, because `ls` is a program, generally kept in `/bin`, so using `/bin/ls *` will work, where `ls *` won't.

Comment: I use /bin/ls * command and I got all the directory names in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

1. Turn on show hidden files. (I used a small app)
2. Check for .profile file in finder
3. Open the file using Text editor
4. Erase the wrong path.
5. Save the .profile file
6. Exit the command prompt and enter the command prompt.
7. Try ls command. It works

***Not magic